# Display the actual data instead of a table using SQLFORM.grid

Tags: web2py

Good day!

I decided to ask new question since Anthony solve my problem.

Based on the given code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823946/insert-multiple-data-using-sqlfrom-grid-with-selectable-signature-in-another-tab). I want to display the actual value not the ID when displaying the data in SQLFORM.grid.

```
School Year    Adviser   Student
1              walker    1
```

Note: walker is the username

this data retrieving is ok but I want is more in informative way.

I want to display in SQLFORM.grid are like this:

```
School Year    Adviser         Student
2015-16-1      Walker, Paul    Doe, John
```

is this possible in SQLFORM.grid?

these are the codes before calling the SQLFORM.grid

```
db.stud_adviser.sy_id.default= db.school_year.sy
db.stud_adviser.adv_id.default= db.auth_user.last_name
db.stud_adviser.stud_id.default= db.student_list.lastname
```

but still the result is the same:

```
School Year    Adviser   Student
1              walker    1
```

nothing happen. BUT when editing the data using SQLFORM.grid the result are working. Because these are the codes I used.

```
db.stud_adviser.sy_id.requires= IS_IN_DB(db, 'school_year.id', '%(sy)s')
db.stud_adviser.adv_id.requires=IS_IN_DB(db,'auth_user.id', '%(last_name)s')
db.stud_adviser.stud_id.requires=IS_IN_DB(db,'student_list.id', '%(lastname)s')
```

but as a programmer you don't want the user to view the students (currently we have 300+ infoTech students) one by one by clicking the edit in SQLFORM.grid just to know who is Student # 1, what School Year is # 1 and who is the Adviser that uses the walker username.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't do this:

```
db.stud_adviser.sy_id.default= db.school_year.sy
db.stud_adviser.adv_id.default= db.auth_user.last_name
db.stud_adviser.stud_id.default= db.student_list.lastname
```

Defaults must be either actual values or functions that return values -- they cannot be `Field` objects (and it's not even clear what the above assignments would mean).

Second, there is no need to explicitly set the `requires` attributes of those fields -- if you instead set the `format` attribute of each table, any fields that reference those tables will receive a default `requires` attribute and a default `represent` attribute based on the `format` attribute of the referenced table.

The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32833280/440323) is almost exactly what you need -- the only difference is that you now want slightly different formatting of the display values (i.e., you now want "Lastname, Firstname" instead of just "Lastname"). So, instead of setting the `format` attributes to `'%s(lastname)s'` and `'%s(last_name)s'`, change them to `'%s(lastname)s, %(firstname)s'` and `'%s(last_name)s, %(first_name)s'`.

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony while I'm on school experimenting the code, I successfully (hope so) manage to show what output I want. For the Adviser and Student column it shows the Last name and First name but the School Year still ID, here's the code:

db1.py

```
db.define_table('school_year',
            Field('sy',),
            Field('current_year', 'boolean'),
            format='%(sy)s')

db.define_table('adviser',
            Field('sy_id', 'reference school_year', label='School Year'),
            Field('adv_id', 'reference auth_user', label='Adviser'))

db.define_table('student_list',
            Field('lastname'),
            Field('firstname'),
            Field('middlename'),
            Field('address'),
            format='%s, %s' % ('%(lastname)s', '%(firstname)s'))
#           format=('%(lastname)s', '%(firstname)s'))

db.define_table('stud_adviser',
            Field('sy_id', 'string', 'reference school_year', label='School Year'),
            Field('adv_id', 'reference auth_user', label='Adviser'),
            Field('stud_id', 'reference student_list', label='Student', unique=True))
```

controller:

```
def myStudent():

    db.stud_adviser.id.readable=False
    db.auth_user._format = '%s, %s' % ('%(last_name)s', '%(first_name)s')
    form = SQLFORM.grid(db.stud_adviser, csv=False, create=False, details=False, editable=False)
    return locals()
```

for the Full name on the Adviser table I use your code:

```
db.auth_user._format = '%(last_name)s', '%(first_name)s'
```

the result the Adviser change to IDs but if I change it to:

```
db.auth_user._format = '%s, %s' % ('%(last_name)s', '%(first_name)s')
```

and it worked.

same also in the student_list, the data change to IDs if I use this code:

```
format=('%(lastname)s', '%(firstname)s'))
```

I want to post an image here but my reputation is not enough.

Comment: Are you sure that your `'%(last_name)s', '%(first_name)s'` equals to Anthony's   `'%(last_name)s, %(first_name)s'` ? `Table.Format` can be a string or Lambda, not tuple.

Comment: Note: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a forum. You posted this as an answer to your question, but it is further information. On stackoverflow, you do not discuss problems. You try to express your problem in a question as short as possible and get answers and choose the answer that solved your problem.